# Getting operator does not exist: record = character varying error, while executing query from repo class

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to execute below query from repo class

```
@Query(value = "select alert_id,event_id,created_ts,created_user from product_config.alert_event_map where (alert_id,event_id) in (:combStr)",nativeQuery=true)
    List<Object[]> fetchAlertDummy(@Param("combStr") String value);
```

But I'm getting below error

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: record = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 112
```

Invoking repo class method like below,

```
StringBuilder strBul=new StringBuilder();
            strBul.append("(1,1)").append(",").append("(7,8)");
            List<Object[]> objArr = alertEventMapRepo.fetchAlertDummy(strBul.toString());
```

But the same query working fine in Postgresql DB,

```
select alert_id,event_id,created_ts,created_user from product_config.alert_event_map where (alert_id,event_id) in ((1,1),(7,8))
```

Here alert_id and event_id are numeric column. I'm trying to combine two columns in where clause. Please help me here, How to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try supplying a collection (e.g. List) of strings instead of a single concatenated String.

Comment: @jboot, I have tried to pass it as List<String>, but getting same error

Comment: Ah, I think it's because you're still getting a query similar to `(alert_id,event_id) in ('(1,1)', '(7,8)')`. So you're not getting tuples, but strings. I don't know exactly how to do it, but I would start experimenting using nested lists (e.g. `List<List<Integer>>`) if I were you. You might need another (perhaps even custom made) class that translates into a record instead of an array. Another option could be to find some PostgreSQL casting mechanism to turn them into records. Lastly you could also look into PostgreSQL arrays in combination with the `var = ANY(array)` expression.

Comment: @jboot, I tried List<List<Integer>>, but getting same error